# Open Source Vulnerability scanning tool to find JSON Injection issues

Tags: owasp, zap, burp

I have to do a vulnerability scan in our web application to find JSON Injection issues. I tried in OWASP ZAP, Burp Suite but not able to find the issues. Could anyone suggest a good open source vulnerability scanning tool where I can find the JSON Injection issues.

Comment: Is the app public, or can you provide us with details of the vulnerabilities? If so we can enhance ZAP to detect them...

Comment: @SimonBennettsopp is not public. But we got few issues where application reacts to inputs in a way that suggests it might be vulnerable to some kind of server-side code injection.

Comment: "suggests it might be vulnerable" - so you dont know? Have you tried using the OAST add-on? https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/oast-support/

If that doesnt find anything and you're still concerned then you can try manual testing using the ZAP fuzzer. 

Automated scanners will not find all possible vulnerabilities - manual testing by a skilled professional will be better. But also more time consuing and expensive :)

Comment: What are you calling "JSON injection issues"?

Comment: Probably https://github.com/anchore/grype/ is your best bet but what do you mean by JSON injection issues? do you know the vulnerability you are looking for?